# how to check that a list contains another list C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two List of domain entities,

First one is Item List, Structure:

```
string ItemID;
string ItemName;
int Qty;
double price;
```

Another one is Offer List, Structure:

```
int OfferID;
string ItemID;
int OfferPrice;
```

Having two variables like this,

```
List<DomainEntities.Items> ItemList=new List<DomainEntities.Items>();
List<DomainEntities.Offers> OfferList=new List<DomainEntities.Offers>();
```

Now i wanted to filter from ItemList.ItemID property which contains OfferList.ItemID, Output should be List.

How to do this filtration?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this

```
ItemList.Where(item => OfferList.Any(offer => offer.ItemID == item.ItemID)).ToList();
```

You can also do this (may perform faster)

```
ItemList.Join(OfferList, item => item.ItemID, offer => offer.ItemID, (item, offer) => item).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

If the lists get large (more than 100 elements each), you should look into a faster lookup strategy, such as the one offered by `HashSet<T>`.

```
List<DomainEntities.Items> itemList = new List<DomainEntities.Items>();
List<DomainEntities.Offers> offerList = new List<DomainEntities.Offers>();

var offerSet = new HashSet<string>(offerList.Select(o => o.ItemID));
var output = itemList.Where(item => offerSet.Contains(item.ItemID)).ToList();
```

The advantage of `HashSet<T>` is that it offers constant performance on lookups, irrespective of its size. Thus, if `itemList` contains *m* elements and `offerList` contains *n* elements, the code above will require roughly *n* operations to build the hash set, but then only takes 1 step to compare any item against it. Thus, it would take a total of *m* steps to filter all elements of `itemList` against it.

By contrast, calling `offerList.Any` requires iterating through its elements each time, effectively resulting in a nested loop. Thus, that approach would require a total of *m*×*n* steps, rather than *m*+*n*. This becomes significant for large collections -- if the two lists contain 1,000 elements each, the `HashSet<T>` approach would take 2,000 steps, whilst the nested loop would take 1,000,000 steps. (I am using the term "steps" loosely here; I'm actually referring to [algorithmic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity).)

The `Join` operator offers a similar optimization to `HashSet<T>` under the hood.